# C++ Templates - undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, header

```
//includes, using etc.
int main()
{
    List<int> a;
    cout << a.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}


//list.h
template <class T>
class List{

int items;

public:
List();
~List();

int size() const;

};

//list.cpp
#include "list.h"
template<class T>
List<T>::List() :
items(0)
{}

template<class T>
List<T>::~List()
{}

template<class T>
int List<T>::size() const
{   return items;   }
```

This should work, shouldn't it? When I define list.h's and list.cpp's content above the main function, everything works fine. However, this gives me some errors :

> main.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `List<int>::List()'
>
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to`List::size() const'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `List<int>::~List()'
>
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to`List::~List()'

when I change `List<int> a;` in the main function to `List<int> a();` the only Error I get is this :

> main.cpp:10:12: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘a’, which is of
>   non-class type ‘List()’

Help me, what'S wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Template must definition and implementation must be in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is a template class and (most of the times) this means that its code must be in the header file.

In addition,

```
List<int> a();
```

is the declaration of a function called `a` that returns a `List<int>`. I emphasize: `a` is not a default-initialized object of type `List<int>`.

Comment: Thank  you!!!!  `must be in the header file` saved my life!